# Combinatorics problem poker

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm getting the wrong answer here and would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

**Problem**: Three people are playing poker, Jessica, Adam and Ida. There's a Ace of spades, Queen of diamonds and a 10 of clubs on the table. Ida have a Queen of spades and a 10 of spades in her hand.

**question**: How many different pair of cards could Adam and Jessica have so that both have a better poker hand than Ida's?

**My solution:**
So I first calculate that there's 33 possible hands that are better than Ida. Then there's (33 c 2) possible hands for one fo the two guys and the other guy are left with (31 c 2) hands? This gives me the answer (33 c 2) + (31 c 2) = 993 but the answer is supposed to be 822. I'm doing something wrong here, how am I supposed to handle it?

Comment: Don't overcount! Just an example. Adam and Jessica cannot have both a pair of queens. Did you consider that ?

Comment: @Peter Hmm no I didn't. I don't think I got it right this time either, but considering what you siad: If the first guy has AQ then there's 3 combinations for second guy to get AQ too, the same goes with AT, if the first guy has AA then there's 0 combinations of AA for the second guy, the same goes for QQ and TT. And then if the first guy has KJ then there's 9 combinations for KJ left for the second guy. That gives me (33 c 2) + (15 c 2) = 633 :/

Comment: I suggest you first think of what constitute a better poker hand. Then work on each cases. I don't play poker, but if I'm not wrong, a better hand would be either $\{A, 10\}, \{A,Q\}, \{K, K\}, \{A, A\}, \{10, 10\}$ or $\{Q, Q\}$. Post your working for each cases for verification here.

Comment: @yh016 A better hand would be AT, AQ, AA, QQ, TT or KJ. By working on each case, do you mean that I for example should give Jessica AT and then check how that affects all the cases and do that for all 6 cases? :)

Comment: @yh016 I don't know if i got it right but if I give AQ to Jessica then there's 24 combinations left for Adam, if I give AT to Jessica then there's 24 combinations left for Adam, if I give AA to Jessica then there's 22 combinations left for Adam, if I give QQ to Jessica then there's 26 combinations left for Adam, if I give TT to Jessica then there's 26 combinations left for Adam, if I give KJ to Jessica then there's 26 combinations left for Adam. If this is right, what do i do with those results?

Comment: You have misread the problem. The problem requires BOTH Adam and Jessica have a better poker hand than Ida.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since on the table and in Ida's hand, there are $\spadesuit$A, $\diamondsuit$Q, $\heartsuit$Q, $\clubsuit$10, $\spadesuit$10. Adam and Jessica cannot possibly have these cards.

A hand that is better than Ida's would be either

(a) Ace, 10

(b) Ace, Queen

(c) Ace, Ace

(d) Queen, Queen

(e) 10, 10

(f) King, Jack

Example, in the case (b) that both Adam and Jessica have the hand of an Ace and a Queen,

there are $P(3,2)\times P(2,2) = 3\times 2\times 2\times 1 = 12$ possibilities.

Now, work out the number of possibilities for the remaining cases, and then sum them up.

Comment: Okay, so that gives me 106. (King, King) doesn't beat Ida so there are only 6 cases.  What now?

Comment: You have solved the problem! Check with someone that your answer is correct.

Comment: The correct answer is supposed to be 822 so there must be something i'm forgetting.

Comment: Just doing the case of both Adam and Jessica have the hand consisting of "a King and a Jack" gives 144 possibilities. Please check your work again.

Comment: For case (king, jack) I did P(4,2) × P(3,2) = 72. Oh wait I should take P(4,2) × P(4,2) then?

Comment: Note that all $4$ Kings and $4$ Jacks are in the remaining deck of cards. So the correct answer is $P(4,2) \times P(4,2)$. You may have made the same mistake for the other cases. Check your work again.

Comment: Okay so this is what i did for the cases now: AQ = P(3,2) × P(2,2), AT = P(3,2) × P(2,2), AA = P(3,2), QQ = P(2,2), TT = P(2,2), KJ = P(4,2) × P(4,2)